# Drop columns from a data frame but I keep getting this error below

Tags: analytics, data-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzInC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9P7EL.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wa0Sf.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjWiT.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPWfP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd1Lh.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3pRa.png)

No matter how I try to code this in R, I still cannot drop my columns so that I can build my logistic regression model. I tried to run it two different ways

> cols<-c("EmployeeCount","Over18","StandardHours")

> Trainingmodel1 <- DAT_690_Attrition_Proj1EmpAttrTrain[-cols,]
> Error in -cols : invalid argument to unary operator

> cols<-c("EmployeeCount","Over18","StandardHours")

> Trainingmodel1 <- DAT_690_Attrition_Proj1EmpAttrTrain[!cols,]
> Error in !cols : invalid argument type

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem:

```
Trainingmodel1 <- DAT_690_Attrition_Proj1EmpAttrTrain[ , !colnames(DAT_690_Attrition_Proj1EmpAttrTrain) %in% cols]
```

Please note that if you want to drop **columns**, you should put your code inside `[` on the right side of the comma, not on the left side.
So `[, your_code]` not `[your_code, ]`.

Here is an example of dropping columns using the code above.

```
cols <- c("cyl", "hp", "wt")
mtcars[, !colnames(mtcars) %in% cols]

#                      mpg  disp drat  qsec vs am gear carb
# Mazda RX4           21.0 160.0 3.90 16.46  0  1    4    4
# Mazda RX4 Wag       21.0 160.0 3.90 17.02  0  1    4    4
# Datsun 710          22.8 108.0 3.85 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Hornet 4 Drive      21.4 258.0 3.08 19.44  1  0    3    1
# Hornet Sportabout   18.7 360.0 3.15 17.02  0  0    3    2
# Valiant             18.1 225.0 2.76 20.22  1  0    3    1
#...
```

**Edit to Reproduce the Error**

The error message you got indicates that there is a column that has only one, identical value in all rows.

To show this, let's try a logistic regression using a subset of `mtcars` data, which has only one, identical values in its `cyl` column, and then we use that column as a predictor.

```
mtcars_cyl4 <- mtcars |> subset(cyl == 4)
mtcars_cyl4
#                 mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# Datsun 710     22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
# Merc 240D      24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
# Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
# Fiat 128       32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
# Honda Civic    30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
# Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
# Toyota Corona  21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
# Fiat X1-9      27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
# Porsche 914-2  26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
# Lotus Europa   30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
# Volvo 142E     21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2

glm(am ~ as.factor(cyl) + mpg + disp, data = mtcars_cyl4, family = "binomial")

#Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
#  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Now, compare it with the same logistic regression by using full `mtcars` data, which have various values in `cyl` column.

```
glm(am ~ as.factor(cyl) + mpg + disp, data = mtcars, family = "binomial")

# Call:  glm(formula = am ~ as.factor(cyl) + mpg + disp, family = "binomial", 
#            data = mtcars)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)  as.factor(cyl)6  as.factor(cyl)8              mpg             disp  
# -5.08552          2.40868          6.41638          0.37957         -0.02864  
# 
# Degrees of Freedom: 31 Total (i.e. Null);  27 Residual
# Null Deviance:        43.23 
# Residual Deviance: 25.28  AIC: 35.28
```

It is likely that, even though you have drop three columns that have one,identical values in all the respective rows, there is another column in `Trainingmodel1` that has one identical values. The identical values in the column were probably resulted during filtering the data frame and splitting data into training and test groups. Better to have a check by using `summary(Trainingmodel1)`.

**Further edit**

I have checked the `summary(Trainingmodel1)` result, and it becomes clear that EmployeeNumber has one identical value (called "level" for a factor) in all rows. To run your regression properly, either you drop it from your model, or if EmployeeNumber has another level and you want to include it in your model, you should make sure that it contains at least two levels in the training data. It is possible to achieve that during splitting by repeating the random sampling until the randomly selected EmployeeNumber samples contain at least two levels. This can be done by looping using `for`, `while`, or `repeat`. It is possible, but I don't know how proper the repeated sampling is for your study.

As for your question about subsetting more than one variable, you can use `subset` and conditionals. For example, you want to get a subset of `mtcars` that has `cyl == 4` **and** `mpg > 20` :

```
mtcars |> subset(cyl == 4 & mpg > 20 )
```

If you want a subset that has `cyl == 4` **or** `mpg > 20`:

```
mtcars |> subset(cyl == 4 | mpg > 20 )
```

You can also subset by using more columns as subset criteria:

```
mtcars |> subset((cyl > 4 & cyl <8) |  (mpg > 20 & gear > 4 ))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was able to drop the columns it seems like but when I go to build my logistics regression model I get this error. It's still telling me I have columns with only one vector but all those columns have been dropped







> Trainingmodel1=glm(formula = formula, data=TrainingData,family = "binomial")
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand the error because no data is available. It would be very helpful if you provide small sample of your data (or similar data) so other users can check.

Comment: I added the data set to the original question, the target variable is Attrition, if you could please take a look that would be helpful

Comment: OK. Could you show me your code that you wrote to run the logistic regression?

Comment: added all my code with outputs up until the error I am getting -- the code I used to run the model is : Trainingmodel1<-glm(formula = formula, data=TrainingData,family = "binomial")

Comment: OK. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: I did run the summary(Trainingmodel1) command and it looks like maybe EmployeeNumber is what's causing the error, could you check? I add the images above. Also how would I subset multiple variables? I see that yours only has the one variable but I have multiple

Comment: I have checked it. Please see further edit in my answer.